# How to fix "OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: YOUR_APP_ID}"

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign-In into my Android app by following the guide from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in.  However, I've found the following error in the "Run" window **BEFORE** and **AFTER** logging in even the app is working fine:

"E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: YOUR_APP_ID}"

I am not sure what is the root cause.  Can someone please help?

regards,
Brian

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static String TAG = "TAG LoginActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 205;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    context = getBaseContext();

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onclick 1");
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    signIn();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {

        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        updateUI(null);
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    updateUI(account);
}

private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

    if (account != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem solved.  I removed  "implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.1.0'" from the build.gradle and all error messages were gone.